# Precision Rectifier Circuit to detect peaks

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I have a question about speed at detecting peaks.

Essentially, my question is that I have a precision rectifier with a capacitor equipped to the end of it to smooth the incoming full bridge 
rectified wave, which works 100%.

however I am concerned, as the application is to play audio through this and capture the current peak. I am worried that the peaks won't be captured in time as audio changes very quickly worst case 1/20kHz.

I understand I need a resistor to discharge the cap so it can change on the next cycle, however when I put a low value resistor (For a faster discharge time) it doesn't reach my peak value anymore oppose to using a big resistor or no resistor which is important as the next stage is a comparator with a fixed Vref to compare to.

How do I balance this? I need a resistor value that can discharge the capacitor fast enough for incoming music in order to capture the peaks of that instant moment. Or is that the trade off?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwwp9Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Must you TRACK the peaks, or simply find the next and higher peak?

Comment: Tracking the peaks would be preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C2 is too big for this sort of application. The OPA350 is only capable of 80mA  of output current and it takes a long time to charge the 680uF cap. You then also need then a very small R3 value to discharge it rapidly between peaks.

Set C2 at about 2uF and R3=100k Ohm

That will give you reasonable peak capture and a decay time in the 200mS range. If you need to make this voltage available elsewhere you could add another OPA350 as a buffer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZJyFZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I shall try it out ! Give me a minute

Comment: Datasheet sheet says around 40mA? and I did what you said, it ripples a lot oppose to before where it was straight

Comment: Yup, the circuit feedback is loading the peak capacitor. If you eliminate R3 and replace R1 and R2 with 100k Ohm you should get the right result. Most peak detectors are arranged a little differently, see here (page 32): http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla140b/snla140b.pdf

Comment: I see I see, would you be able to explain the logic on why eliminate R3 and replace R1? I would imagine you need a discharge resistor for the cap to be empty for the new audio signal, cause what if the cap is charged to 1.96V due to the previous and the next audio amplitude is coming in however the cap is still at 1.96V and this amplitude is 0.5V wouldnt the cap still be charged at 1.96V then?

Comment: I think its personally working more accurate to be honest, but I have no idea why those changes :/

Comment: When the AC signal is negative going, the opamp output is positive going, forward biases the diode and captures the peak voltage up to VCC -VF. When the input signal is positive going the opamp clamps at zero. Because of this there is no feedback and C2 is discharged through the feedback resistors (it's complicated because of the positive Vin). You could fix this by putting 100k Ohms from the -ve input of the opamp to ground which would be more accurate.

Comment: I updated the schematic is this what you mean?

Comment: I added a schematic to the answer

Comment: I just dont understand how C2 is being discharged through the feedback resistors when the positive cycle's current is going through the feedback resistor towards C2 and charging it? Isnt the C2 cap getting charged for every cycle?

Comment: If Vin is -high, then C2 is charged ...you are happy with that, and it's charging to the peak. If Vin is +high then the opamp is clamped to zero output (it's a single rail device with only +5V supply). Since the opamp input is no longer being driven to zero (it is normally = to + Vin of the opamp). So +Vin(opamp) will be at some point set positive by part of Vinput divisor (R1/R4)  and the C2 divisor (R2/R4), so C2 discharges very little. If Vinput is zero (no signal), then R1/R4 are in parallel (50k) and C2 discharges with 150k Ohm.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, adding the resistor there discharges the cap quicker, however wouldn't that resistor affect the gain of the op amp when Vin is High?

Comment: Appreciate the effort thank you! I understand it now